# Font loading in X server

Tags: x11, xorg, fonts

A `.ttf` (or more specificaly some characters from `Unifont.ttf`) fail to load directly for a script that runs on `.xprofile`, running:

```
fc-list  > fc-list.log
```

On `.xprofile` before the script in question shows the font loaded correctly, any way I can find if another `.ttf` is causing the problem or if it is something else?

Answer (score 0):

It was the locale . . .
probably with one of my resent portage world updates or something else I did my locale changed from "en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8" to "POSIX"
I just stambled uppon the word locale on a forum while looking for an answer and thought that I haven't checked that yet;trully lucky, I wourld have had to spend days on it for sure.